# OpenCV python GTK implementation error

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

I was trying to build opencv 3.2.0 from source for python3.5 in my ubuntu 16.04. When I cmake the targets it showed GTK+ 2.X yes. But after everything is completed successfully I am still getting error for cv2.imshow saying "function not implemented. Please build with GTK+ 2.X or carbon support".

I tried possible solution with QT5 as well. Nothing did work. If possible kindly help.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem